# How to bind value sql query in laravel?

Tags: laravel, orm

I have a query. Query is include sql function. So I want to directly. But I need parameter.

```
$parameters = DB::select("SELECT GetFlowPropertyValue(flow.id, 'PCommonLineDataNumber') subscriberNumber, (SELECT Id FROM ConfigurationItem WHERE FlowId = flow.id ORDER BY Id DESC Limit 1) ConfigurationItemId, GetObjectTypeRelationParentObjectValue(6, 1, flow.id) CustomerId, GetFlowPropertyValue(flow.id, 'MainOfferingName') MainOfferingName, GetFlowPropertyValue(flow.Id, 'CampaignName') CampaignName FROM akislar flow WHERE id ='$query->id'");
```

As you can see, Final parameter come foreach but doesnt run. I use dd and I write query.
I see $query->id is look like empty. It is not defined.
How can I bind $query->id ?

Comment: What is `$query`? It's only referenced in your code as `$query->id`, but you never define it anywhere, like `$query = ...`. Also, if `id` is numeric, why are you wrapping it in single quotes `'`? Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73623906/edit) and include more details, such as how you're defining `$query`, any errors, etc.

Comment: query defined top. I explain it. It's a foreach($querys as $query){db:select ... }

Comment: So why don't you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73623906/edit) and include how you're defining `$querys`? It's the same issue; we don't know what `$query` (or `$querys`) is, so we're limited on how we can help you.

Comment: Because Tim doesnt matter query where is come. I define anywhere in the class. I can see dd($query) result. It's not problem. Problem is when I write querty $query->id its not work.

Comment: Well sorry, if you aren't willing to update your question to show more details I'm requesting, then I can't help you. I don't understand what your problem is, you keep saying "doesn't run", "its not work", etc., but unless we can see and/or reproduce the issue, we won't be able to help.

Comment: `"SELECT ... WHERE id = " . $query->id);`?